# TypeOf(RegisterPage) showing an error

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, frame, mobile-application

I am developing a windows 8.1 app and this is my first time doing this. I have coded in c# before but I'm still in the learning stages due to being on and off on learning.

I've just started so I only have two pages : `MainPage.xaml` and `RegisterPage.xaml`.
The  `MainPage` has a button labeled `Register` when clicked, will take me over to the `RegisterPage`.
Been looking around the net for a way to do this and I find the use of `Frame.Navigate(typeof(RegisterPage));` , but when I enter this in to the `button_click event`, it doesn't seem to recognize the `RegisterPage`

Here is the Main Page:

```
namespace FoodOrderingApp
{

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(RegisterPage));

    }
}
```

Any help and explanations would be appreciated!
I've also added screenshot what Visual Studios 2015 shows on the code.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you are trying

```
Frame.Navigate(RegisterPage));
```

you should use instead

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(RegisterPage)));
```

and the navigation framework will create an object of the RegisterPage class and load it as the new active page.

If the compiler does not recognize RegisterPage, check in what namespace is that class declared